# JQGrid - Add buttons to a Form Edit dialog

Tags: forms, button, jqgrid, edit

I have been using JQGrid for about a year now and I love it.  Just wondering if someone knows a way to add a button or two that will trigger my own code on a Form Edit page?  Not on the grid itself - the edit dialog.

Would I just use the onInitializeForm event?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery to do this.  In my case I had a drop-down select item as a field on the edit for and I wanted to add a link next to it.  I used the beforeShowForm event.

```
beforeShowForm: function(form) {
           $("#MyDropDownList").after("<a href='#' id='link'>A Link To Something</a>");
       },
```

Hope this helps, even though it's a few weeks late.